# XCode debug error Thread 1

Tags: ios, xcode, development, error, swift

Ok so I'm trying to work with swift on XCode but every time I start to run my code I get this

`Thread 1 Queue: com.apple.main-thread(serial)`

What does this mean?, and how do I fix it? Also i've started a new project with the same code to make sure theres no unnecessary code mistakes. However I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe as an error, it's not. That is the main queue where the program runs. You will see that queue every time you run a program.

[image]